# How can I implement the command 'ls' with wildcard, '*'?

Tags: unix, system-calls

EDIT #1 : I'm under the limit that all arguments are enclosed in two quotes, so that shell do not expand any argument with `*` to the corresponding path.

EDIT #2 : In order to retrieve directories such as `*/*`, `../*`, and `dirA/*/file.out`, How should I use iteration loop or recursive call?

I have just learned about the function `fnmatch()`. But I don't know start place.
There are many possible cases. I'm confused dealing with these all cases.
For example, Let me assume that executable program is `a.out`.

```
$./a.out -l */*
$./a.out -l ../*
$./a.out -l [file_name] [directory_name] 
/* Since I also have to implement ls command with no wildcard. */
```

What should I do? Any advice would be awesome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be aware that your shell expands the `*` before it eer gets to your executable...

Comment: Quick note : most shells replace * themselves.. When you run `ls *` in bash, the arguments that `ls` receives are the names of all the files in the current directory, not `*`. So to provide this functionality, you'll have to escape your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is : shell replaces wildcard caracter * with all of the filenames matching the pattern.

Solution:

If you do not want to use this feature of bash, just put quotation marks around your command line arguments.

Calling your program that way will have the original arguments, containing wildcards.

After this, you can list all the filenames with their paths. For example using some recursive algorithm. Then you can apply some matching to these path string. (when visiting it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a good unix citizen, the rule is **Don't do filename globbing unless you are writing a shell.**

You want to write an `ls`-like program? Don't do any wildcard expansion. Don't treat "*" specially. Just treat your `argv` as a list of filenames. If your program handles these cases:

```
./a.out file1
./a.out file1 file2 file3
```

Then it will also handle

```
./a.out file*
```

correctly because the shell will do the expansion and your program won't need to know about it. And besides that, it will handle this:

```
zsh% ./a.out **/file<40-185>~file<90-100>(.mm-30OL[1,2])
```

which in zsh expanded glob syntax means: expand file40 through file185, except for file90 through file100, include only the ones that have been modified in the last 30 minutes, and use only the largest 2 files in the resulting set.

`fnmatch` is never going to do anything like that. But these fancy globs can be used with any command that just takes a filename list and doesn't care where it came from.

When you're in a situation where you can't take a list of filenames from the command line, then consider using fnmatch. `ls` isn't one of those situations.

Comment: There are *some* other commands that do their own wildcard expansion, such as `find`.

Comment: @KeithThompson sure there are exceptions, and `find` is a big one, since finding files is its central purpose. And things like `unzip` want to glob names that exist in the archive, not the filesystem. But the reaction to "I'm implementing ls with wildcards" has to be "ARGH NO!"